# rotating bone with quaternion issue

Tags: c++, rotation, quaternions

I need to rotate bones of skeleton, i have already the quaterinion corresponding for each joints; and i am confused when it comes on rotating.

[Skeleton to move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwGbB.png) is my opengl scene i need to move.

My problem is that i can't rotate the joint; Can anyone Help

Bellow is my code

//i evaluate each joint to get the translation and rotation.

```
    void Node::EvaluatePoi(std::vector<POI> pois, const Vector &par_pos,
                               const Quaternion &par_rot, Vector Node::*world_pos,std::vector<Arti> joints)
        {  Vector poi=this->PoiVec ;
        
                Quaternion rot;
                if (pois.empty()){
                    this->*world_pos= this->rest_position ;//OFFSET
        
                    rot= this-> rest_rotation ;//identity
        
                }else{
                if(this->name=="Hips")
                {
                 this->*world_pos = eval_instant_positionPOI(poi);
             
                   rot= this-> rest_rotation ;// do not rotate
                }else if(this->name=="LeftUpLeg")
                {
                    this->*world_pos = this->rest_position;// set to OFFSET
                  
                      rot= this-> rest_rotation ;// do not rotate
                }else if(this->name=="RightUpLeg")
                {
                    this->*world_pos = this->rest_position;
                      rot= this-> rest_rotation ;
                }
        
                else
        
                {
                 this->*world_pos= this->rest_position; 
         
                     rot= eval_instant_rotationPOI(joints);
                }
                }
 //Applying transformation on the global position with rot =qparent * qchild
               
                (this->*world_pos).rotate(par_rot);
                this->*world_pos += par_pos;
               
               rot = par_rot * rot;
                
    
                // draw joint's subhierarchy
                for (int i = 0; i < n_children; i++)
                    child[i]->EvaluatePoi(pois, this->*world_pos, rot, world_pos,joints);
        }
```

EDIT:
//here i get the local rotation of each joint, after that create quaternions equivalent to individual Euler rotations and then compose to one rotation

```
Vector x_vector(1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
       y_vector(0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
       z_vector(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
Quaternion Node::eval_instant_rotationPOI( std::vector<Arti> joints)
{

    Quaternion roto;//= new Quaternion();
    Quaternion sample;

 double t= 0.02;
 Vector v;
 Vector Euler(0,0,0);;


string x =this->name;
if(x== "Head"){
    Euler=GetEulers(joints,JOINT_HEAD);
}else if(x== "Neck"){
     Euler=GetEulers(joints,JOINT_NECK);
}
else if(x== "LeftUpArm"){
     Euler=GetEulers(joints,JOINT_LEFT_SHOULDER);
}
else if(x== "RightUpArm"){
     Euler=GetEulers(joints,JOINT_RIGHT_SHOULDER);
}
else if(x== "LeftLowArm"){
     Euler=GetEulers(joints,JOINT_LEFT_ELBOW);
}
else if(x== "LeftHand"){
     Euler=GetEulers(joints,JOINT_LEFT_HAND);
}
else if(x== "RightLowArm"){
     Euler=GetEulers(joints,JOINT_RIGHT_ELBOW);
}
else if(x== "RightHand"){
     Euler=GetEulers(joints,JOINT_RIGHT_HAND);
}
else if(x== "Hips"){
     Euler=GetEulers(joints,JOINT_TORSO);
}
else if(x== "LeftUpLeg"){
     Euler=GetEulers(joints,JOINT_LEFT_HIP);
}
else if(x== "RightUpLeg"){
     Euler=GetEulers(joints,JOINT_RIGHT_HIP);
}
else if(x== "LeftLowLeg"){
     Euler=GetEulers(joints,JOINT_LEFT_KNEE);
}
else if(x== "LeftFoot"){
     Euler=GetEulers(joints,JOINT_LEFT_FOOT);
}
else if(x== "RightLowLeg"){
     Euler=GetEulers(joints,JOINT_RIGHT_KNEE);
}
else if(x== "RightFoot"){
     Euler=GetEulers(joints,JOINT_RIGHT_FOOT);
}
   

Quaternion qx(x_vector, (Euler.x ));
Quaternion qy(y_vector, (Euler.y ));
Quaternion qz(z_vector, (Euler.z ));
  sample = qz  * qy * qx;
   
roto= slerp(qTemp, sample, t);
qTemp=roto;

 return roto ;
}
```

/*here i multiply the joint and its parent to get the Euler Angle ; is it necessary to convert to
*Euler Angle?*/

```
 Vector Node::GetEulers(std::vector<Arti> joints, const int idx) {
           // Get the quaternion of its parent.
           Quaternion q_parent;
            Quaternion q_current;
           if (idx == JOINT_TORSO) {
               q_parent.identity();
           }
           /////
    
           {
               q_parent = Quaternion(joints[parent_joint_map[idx]].quat.x,
                                      joints[parent_joint_map[idx]].quat.y,
                                      joints[parent_joint_map[idx]].quat.z,
                                      joints[parent_joint_map[idx]].quat.w);
           }
    
           // Get the quaternion of the joint.
            q_current =  Quaternion(joints[idx].quat.x, joints[idx].quat.y,
                                   joints[idx].quat.z, joints[idx].quat.w);
    
           // Calculate the relative quaternion.
          Quaternion q_delta = quat_left_multiply(q_current , quat_inverse(q_parent));
    
             Vector angle = euler_from_quat(q_delta);
           // cout<<this->name<<" "<<angle<<"   ";
    
           return angle;
       }

    Quaternion quat_left_multiply(Quaternion l, Quaternion r) {
               Quaternion q = {r.w * l.x + r.x * l.w + r.y * l.z - r.z * l.y,
                   r.w * l.y + r.y * l.w + r.z * l.x - r.x * l.z,
                   r.w * l.z + r.z * l.w + r.x * l.y - r.y * l.x,
                   r.w * l.w - r.x * l.x - r.y * l.y - r.z * l.z};
               return q;
           }

Vector& Vector::rotate(const Quaternion& q)
{
    Quaternion p(x, y, z, 0.0f);
    Quaternion qc(q);
    qc.conjugate();
    Quaternion pp(q * p * qc);

    x = pp.x;
    y = pp.y;
    z = pp.z;

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: "is it necessary to convert to Euler Angle?" : No. It is unclear what your problem is but anyway, unless you need Euler angles representation, you should convert your quaterion directly to a rotation matrix, to be then combined with other transformations.  "I can't rotate the joint" is not clear enough, please give some explanations. Are your joints, part of a graph, with hierarchical transformations properly computed ?

Comment: well the problem is i tried to rotate the bone position with the quaternion value get from the function GetEuler above, this function provide  the Euler Angle that i reconvert to quaternion after, due to the orientation ZYX , (i don't know if it's necessary ).

Comment: does the quaternion from the joint need any relative calculation before converting to rotation matrix ?

Comment: No, each joint should have its own quaternion repreting its current rotation. Then you can apply a rotation to a joint by multiplying this joint quaternion by another quaternion, representing the amount of rotation to apply (or vice versa depending desired transformation space), the result of this multiplication is the new rotation of your joint. Then, when it come to build the final transform matrix, convert the joint quaternion to a rotation matrix to be combined with the other transformations.

Comment: Concerning euler angles, you may prefer to **input** rotation amount to appy using Euler angles (which is indeed more convenient than using quaternion directly), and in this case, you need to convert Euler angles to a quaternion (to be multiplied with the joint quaternion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotating a quaternion is actually multiplying a quaternion by another. Given the quaternion `qA` representing the current rotation of an object and `qB` the quaternion representing the amount of rotation to apply (to add) to this object, the resulting new rotation of this object is computed as follow (pseudocode):

```
qA = qA * qB;
```

Alternatively, you can apply (add) this rotation in what is called "object" or "local" transformation space by swapping operands:

```
qA = qB * qA
```

Each joint should hold (usualy as class member) a quaternion representing its current rotation in local space. This is probably what you already done. If you want to apply a rotation to that joint, then you simply need multiply the joint quaternion, by another quaternion representing the amount of rotation to apply. A quaterion rotation method can be like this (pseudocode):

```
Joint::Rotate(const quaterion& amount, bool local) 
{
   if(local) {
     this->rotation = amount * this->rotation;
   } else {
     this->rotation = this->rotation * amount;
   }

   this->rotation.normalize();
}
```

That is all you need for the rotation part, **nothing else**. After that, you will need to convert the joint quaternion to a rotation matrix, so to be combined with the other joint transformations (translation, scale, whatever). Here is **one** implementation of the quaternion to rotation matrix conversion (pseudocode):

```
Matrix3 QuaternionToMatrix(const quaternion& q) 
{
    float x2 = q.x + q.x;
    float y2 = q.y + q.y;
    float z2 = q.z + q.z;
    float xx = q.x * x2;
    float xy = q.x * y2;
    float xz = q.x * z2;
    float yy = q.y * y2;
    float yz = q.y * z2;
    float zz = q.z * z2;
    float wx = q.w * x2;
    float wy = q.w * y2;
    float wz = q.w * z2;

    Matrix3 m; //< 3x3 matrix

    m[0] = (1.0f - (yy + zz));
    m[1] = (xy - wz);
    m[2] = (xz + wy);
    m[3] = (xy + wz);
    m[4] = (1.0f - (xx + zz));
    m[5] = (yz - wx);
    m[6] = (xz - wy);
    m[7] = (yz + wx);
    m[8] = (1.0f - (xx + yy));

    return m;
}
```

What you may finally need is to input rotation using Euler angles instead of quaternion values. Indeed, Euler angles are easier to handle and understand when it come to apply a rotation in a human point of view. In this case, you'll need to convert the input Euler angles to a quaternion. Here is **one** possible implementation of Euler angle to quaternion conversion:

```
Quaternion EulerToQuaternion(float x, float y, float z) 
{
    float sx = sinf(x * -0.5f);
    float cx = cosf(x * -0.5f);
    float sy = sinf(y * -0.5f);
    float cy = cosf(y * -0.5f);
    float sz = sinf(z * -0.5f);
    float cz = cosf(z * -0.5f);

    Quaternion q;

    q.x = sx * cy * cz + cx * sy * sz;
    q.y = cx * sy * cz - sx * cy * sz;
    q.z = cx * cy * sz + sx * sy * cz;
    q.w = cx * cy * cz - sx * sy * sz;

    return q;
}
```

Comment: so the quaternion i apply to rotate the local is the quaternion from Euler angle  ?       i don't understand the "  apply (add) this rotation in what is called "object" or "local" transformation space by swapping operands"

Comment: @Nahri this refer to the transformation space, it is hard to explain in short, and unfortunately, there is few documentation available. I think this is a good introduction : https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/Maya-Basics/files/GUID-A63AC5C8-8822-42AC-827E-164B5266DA03-htm.html

Comment: Hi Sir, thanks for the explanation, I have one more problem when applying transformation on joint. I am rotating directly the global position of joint with the quaternion or the rotation matrix you proposed, i commented the code where i apply transfomation  in the first  function above, but there are no movement applyied. can you help what may be wrong in my code

Comment: Sorry but your code is very confusing. `world_pos` seem to be a vector. I even don't realy understant what you are ding by dereferencing a pointer like this `this->*world_pos`, this is very unusual syntax. Anyway this `Vector` has a `rotate` function member that take a quaternion, then, you ADD a Quaternion to this Vector. Sorry but nothing here make sens. Explain what is  `world_pos` , what is the ` `rotate` fuction, what does the `+=` operator to your Quaternions...

Comment: Please provide updated code with elements I given to you. How is the joint final world matrix built ? Where are quaternions multiplied ? Where are stored joint transformations ?... There many essential elements missing and others that appear pointless.

Comment: yes, world_pos is a vec3 refers to the position of the bone in space, and the function rotate make the rotation of the bone position by the quaternion, i'll update when i get back home.

Comment: @Nahri You can't rotate a position vector by a quaternion, this has no sens. The rotation of a 3D object is described by a rotation matrix, which being part of a final transformation matrix combining rotation, translation, scale, etc. If you are not familiard with that, start to study this before quaternion rotations.

Comment: so the quaternion i rotate the vector is a created quaternions equivalent to individual Euler rotations.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your sentence. I repeat, you cannot rotate a vector by a quaternion. If your rotation is stored as euler angle, you have to convert your Euler Angles to Quaternion, perform quaternion rotation, then convert the resulting quaternion to Euler angles. This is inefficient, but possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245160/discussion-between-sedenion-and-nahri).